# preg_match_all - excluding part of a result

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm a bit confused about one thing:
Soo, I've got this preg_match_all line:

```
    preg_match_all('|Producers:</span> (.+?)</div>|m', $pg, $studio);
```

And sometimes in the result there is a string

```
<sup><small>L</small></sup>
```

that I do not want in my $studio variable. How to ignore it?

Comment: By not trying to match an HTML string with a regex.

Comment: To elaborate on @RocketHazmat's point, use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to manipulate and traverse the DOM.

Comment: Post your XML/HTML content and expected output.

Comment: Cannot help without your HTML code.